# Passing parameter packs to a template with parameter non-pack and parameter-pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, parameter-pack

The following code is an error in GCC trunk and Clang trunk:

https://godbolt.org/z/YYzdeh

```
#include <variant>

template <template <typename...> typename Container,
          typename Type,
          typename ... More>
struct Contain
{
    using type = Container<Type, More...>;
};

template <template <typename...> typename Container,
          typename Type>
struct Contain<Container, Type>
{
    using type = Container<Type>;
};

template <template <typename...> typename Container,
          typename Type,
          typename ... More>
using Contain_t = typename Contain<Container, Type, More ...>::type;


template <typename ... A>
using C_ok = typename Contain< std::variant, A ... >::type;


template <typename ... A>
using C_bad = Contain_t< std::variant, A ... >;
```

Why does parameter pack `A` split correctly into `Type` and `More ...` in `C_ok` but not in `C_bad`?

**Fixed:**
Template parameter `Type` in `Contain_t` was redundant.

```
template <template <typename...> typename Container,
          /* typename Type, */
          typename ... More>
using Contain_t = typename Contain<Container, /* Type, */ More ...>::type;
```

(Please ignore that it will not work when called with 0 parameters)

Comment: Notice than specialization for empty `More` for `Contain` is unneeded.

Comment: Indeed, but this is a snippet of minimum code that exposes the problem. In the original code, it is needed,.

Comment: Notice that your aliases "lie", as `C_ok<>` (and `C_Bad<>`) would be incorrect.

Comment: You can fix it by also having `Type, More...` in final aliases [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vfbYhM).

Comment: Your problem can be reduced to [this](https://godbolt.org/z/1156Pj).